# Jenkins WebSphere Deployer Plugin fails. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I try to deploy an EAR file on Websphere 7 with webshepre deployer plugin, I get the error below.

I put the was admin jars on plugin folder. Did I miss another jars?? Test connection is ok.

Webshepre Deployer Plugin Version 1.2

Thanks.

```
Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...

The following artifacts will be deployed in this order...
-------------------------------------------
iwj2eeexample-ear-1.0.1.ear
-------------------------------------------
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:122)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.getAppName(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.createArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:226)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:168)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/content/IContentTypeManager]
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.handleException(AppManagementFactory.java:560)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:128)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:78)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.readArchive(AppDeploymentController.java:210)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:108)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/content/IContentTypeManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.initChildTranslators(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.<init>(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.<init>(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.createRootDOMAdapter(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.doLoad(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.xmltrim.XMLTrimResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(XMLTrimResourceImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.load(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.getMofResource(LoadStrategyImpl.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.getMofResource(ArchiveImpl.java:2228)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptorResource(ModuleFileImpl.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.XmlBasedImportStrategyImpl.primLoadDeploymentDescriptor(XmlBasedImportStrategyImpl.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear12ImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear12ImportStrategyImpl.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear12ImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear12ImportStrategyImpl.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:223)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getEarFile(AppInstallHelper.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfo(AppInstallHelper.java:406)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:118)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentTypeManager
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 50 more

Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is an issue with classloading with the WDP plugin due to the way WebSphere 7 handles classloading. I'm still trying to figure out what causes this issue with WebSphere 7.x servers. I believe you have successfully added the .jar files correctly if you can connect successfully when clicking "Test Connection".